# TFS build/releases do not start. Queue has over 900 entries

Tags: tfs, build

I am using TFS 2018 on-site.  There was an issue with a build and some one paused the queue.  Now the Queue has over 900+ jobs.

I have deleted all the jobs from the Database, but the agents still see 900+ jobs.  I added a new agent to see if that helped but it too sees 900+.

Now no builds are working because of this issue.  Has anyone seen or resolved an issue like this?

[image]

Any and All suggestions are welcomed.

Comment: Well, first off, you should **never, ever, under any circumstances** directly change the database. You may have irreparably damaged your TFS install by doing so. The correct method for dealing with this would have been to use the REST APIs to get a list of queued builds and cancel them. My recommendation would be to restore from a backup (you do have backups, I hope...) and deal with the problem using the correct methodology.

Comment: After cancelling some build, it did not free up the Build Service. So you need to restart the build service.

Comment: No cancelling all the builds didn't free it up.  It looks like one job is hung somewhere in the queue.

Comment: What's the result if you use another agent pool? Have you tried to [clear TFS cache](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/willy-peter_schaub/2010/09/15/if-you-have-problems-with-tfs-or-visual-studio-flush-the-user-cache-or-not/)? And also restart TFS build service and whole TFS server, which may do the trick.

Comment: make sure the tfsjobagent is started and running on the TFS server.

Comment: I added a new agent and it is the above dv-dsylvester-0.  It just showed all the jobs minus 1

Comment: @WannaBDeveloper If clear cache not help in your scenario. Seems like need to dig into database and find root cause. You may have to create an incident to Microsoft technical support https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/support/devops/.  They will help you work on it together.